# How to redirect page using JAVA SCRIPT in codeigniter after clicking on alert message OK button

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

this is script i have used , now i have to redirect after message appears and clicking on that message OK button

```
 $('#save_scheduler').click( function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_uri('shopapp/scheduler_master'); ?>",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#SchedulerForm').serialize(),
                success: function( retdata ) {
                    alert( retdata.msg ),
```

Comment: use `window.location.href = "http://google.com";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another page in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be like this.

alert( retdata.msg );
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a page in JavaScript like this:

```
window.location.replace('http://newpageurl.com/');
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to ask the user first use `confirm`:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
    window.location.replace('http://newpageurl.com/');
}
```

Comment: i have to click on OK button then it should redirect, pls tell the jquery after that

Comment: that msg is already written in retdata.msg, and after that pop message appears but after that it is not redirecting